# Return the ith number of the format x^y, where x and y are integers

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, sequence, dynamic-programming, exponent

x and y are integers greater than 1.
A Special number can be expressed as x^y.
Note that the special number sequence is in ascending order (4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, ...).
Given an integer i, the program should return the ith special number.

```
i=0 -> num=4
i=4 -> num=25
```

Would like some insights. Faced this in a coding round for a company. Brute force ended up with TLEs.

Edit 1: Found a link: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78985/find-the-n-th-perfect-power.

Edit-2: I shared the codegolf link to help check some of the solutions that are already available and are expected to exceed the time limit. I tried both with the Mathematica solution and the sage solution approach, faced TLE on both of them.

Comment: this is off topic. all you've done is repost a code golf question with no effort shown to solve it  (not to mention a one line mathematica solution is given there)

Comment: note the code golf problem allows `x=1`, so that solution needs a (trivial) tweak.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is equivalent to finding an integer `j` where `log_j k` is an integer, and `j` is in a sequence with an upper bound `k` such that `sum [floor(log_j k) - 1 | j <- [2..floor(sqrt k)] == i`

We can make a rough estimate of where the `i`th element would be by binary search with a limited iteration. If we guess the number at `m^2`, the highest base that may be counted is:

```
m
```

Then we can examine lower bases and add up their log counts. For example, `i = 10`:

```
Guess: 10^2
Highest base: 10

Then at minimum we have (10 - 1) + (floor(log2 (10^2)) - 1)
= 15 elements. Too many.


Guess: 5^2 
Highest base: 5
Minimum element count: (5 - 1) + (floor(log2 (5^2)) - 1) = 8

Iterate over logs:
  -- Because of the exponential nature of the problem,
  -- if the guess is too large, the bulk of the elements will appear
  -- early in the iteration; and if it's too small, the limit on
  -- exponents will drop early allowing for early exit in either case.

  [floor(logBase x 25) - 1 | x <- [2..4]] = [3,1,1]
  sum ([1] ++ [3,1,1]) = 6. Too few.


Guess: 7^2
Highest base: 7
Minimum element count: (7 - 1) + (floor(log2 (7^2)) - 1) = 10

Iterate over logs:
  [floor(logBase x 49) - 1 | x <- [2..6]] = [4,2,1,1,1]
  sum ([1] ++ [4,2,1,1,1]) = 10

Answer: 7^2
```